# IllegalStateException while starting Media recorder

Tags: android, illegalstateexception, mediarecorder

I got a problem in getting amplitude in my app.

My **start** method

```
public void start() {
    if (mRecorder == null) {
        try {
            mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

            mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_WB);
            mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_WB);
            mRecorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null");
            try {
                mRecorder.prepare();
                mRecorder.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                    mRecorder = null;
            } catch(IllegalStateException e ){
                e.printStackTrace();
                mRecorder = null;
            }

        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And my **stop** method:

```
public void stop() {
    if (mRecorder != null) {
        try {
            mRecorder.stop();
        } catch (RuntimeException stopException) {
            //handle cleanup here
        } finally {
            mRecorder.release();
        }
        mRecorder = null;
    }
}
```

It throws *IllegalStateException* on

```
mRecorder.start();
```

I tried different OutputFormats and AudioEncoders but none of them was working. :/  Also tried it on different phones.

This is my stacktrace.

```
W/MediaRecorder: mediarecorder went away with unhandled events
E/MediaRecorder: start failed: -38
W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException
W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.oscarsenior.oscar.util.sensorHelpers.SoundMeter.start(SoundMeter.java:33)
W/System.err:     at com.oscarsenior.oscar.util.service.SensorService.updateAmplitude(SensorService.java:616)
W/System.err:     at com.oscarsenior.oscar.util.service.SensorService$6.onSensorChanged(SensorService.java:606)
```

I run this every 15 minutes for 3 seconds to measure max amplitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find the solution to my problem.

The problem was lying in my service. I was using MediaRecorder twice at the same time using same *MediaRecorder.AudioSource*.

The solution for this is to use the same **mRecorder** for both cases.

So I created *Singleton* from my **SoundMeter** class.

```
protected SoundMeter(){

}

public static SoundMeter getInstance(){
    if(instance == null){
        instance = new SoundMeter();
    }
    if(!instance.isRecording || instance.mRecorder == null){
        instance.start();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

So I get instance of **SoundMeter** and if the instance with **mRecorder** is not initialized, I will use same *SoundMeter.start()* method as in question.

I added *mRecorder.reset()* to *stop()* method, so release **mRecorder** will clear its state. Probably I could release **MediaRecorder** once finished not every time I stop listening for a while, but I rather free some memory on background when I do not need it.

```
if (mRecorder != null) {
    try {
        mRecorder.stop();
    } catch (RuntimeException stopException) {
        //handle cleanup here
    } finally {
        mRecorder.reset();
        mRecorder.release();
    }
    mRecorder = null;
    isRecording = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Allow the Permission

```
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Then start() method

```
MediaRecorder mRecorder;
File file;

public void start() {
    if (mRecorder == null) {
        try {
            mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

            file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Demo");
            if (!file.exists())
                file.mkdir();
            mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);

            mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            mRecorder.setOutputFile(file.getAbsoluteFile() + "/demoAudio.mp3");
            mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

            //mRecorder.setOutputFile();
            try {
                mRecorder.prepare();
                mRecorder.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                mRecorder = null;
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                mRecorder = null;
            }

        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Then Stop() method

```
public void stop() {
    if (mRecorder != null) {
        try {
            mRecorder.stop();
        } catch (RuntimeException stopException) {
            //handle cleanup here
        } finally {
            mRecorder.release();
        }
        mRecorder = null;
    }
}
```

And Also stop recording while application is on Backgroud using this method

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    stop();
}
```

Comment: First, you should move the creation of the file outside this class, because it is not relevant to this class. Second I have allowed permissions. Third MediaRecorder is returning error code 38. According to this source, 38 corresponds to ENOSYS. Not very helpful.

Comment: Yes, We have to create the File Before start the MediaRecorder Because If File/Folder is not Exist then it will crash the Application.And its working from my side.I'll check the Error Code 38 and let you know.

Comment: Please check my code again. Here i'm adding one method through which you can't face Error Code 38.Please check and let me know.Thanks

Comment: You do not need to create file you can use /dev/null.

Comment: Apart from this, Other part of code is working or not?

Comment: Sadly, no. Looking for more solutions

Comment: what type of problem are you facing?

Comment: Same as in the question.